# Python: parsing Google API JSON with if/elif/else

Tags: python, json, loops, if-statement, google-api

I'm parsing Google API `JSON` with `Python` and like a cat that mount too high on a tree, I now find myself in a difficult situation.

The code is working, the only problems are the 2 `elif` I'm using:

```
        if response_data2['status'] == 'OK':
            Googleplace_id = response_data2['result']['place_id']
            Googleid = response_data2['result']['id']
            GoogleName = response_data2['result']['name']
            for types in response_data2['result']['address_components']:
                field = types.get('types', [])
                if 'street_number' in field:
                    GoogleStreet_Number = types['long_name']
                elif 'street_number' not in field:
                    GoogleStreet_Number = None
                if 'route' in field:
                    GoogleStreet = types['long_name']
                if 'postal_code' in field:
                    GooglePostal_Code = types['long_name']
                if 'locality' in field:
                    GoogleCity = types['long_name']
                elif 'locality' not in field:
                    GoogleCity = None
                if 'administrative_area_level_1' in field:
                    GoogleArea1 = types['long_name']
                if 'administrative_area_level_2' in field:
                    GoogleArea2 = types['long_name']
                if 'country' in field:
                    GoogleCountry = types['long_name']
                if 'country' in field:
                    GoogleCountryCode = types['short_name']
```

My script gently fill the database but `'street_number'` and `'locality'` are always NULL. and this is clearly because the `if`/`elif` is not working and the script is considering just the 2 `elif` in those 2 cases.

How to create a loop that writes the data `if` the `JSON` element is there, `else`, writes a `None`.

Now is **always** writing a `None` where there is an `else`

Comment: Not sure I understand. It seems that your code should work; have you verified that those fields actually exist or that you have spelt them correctly? Do you have example json? Another thing is that those keys might be nested within something else. It's hard to say without seeing it

Comment: You are using way to many variable names. I suspect just a few lines later you fill them into a database query, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

```
        if response_data2['status'] == 'OK':
            Googleplace_id = response_data2['result'].get("place_id", None)
            Googleid = response_data2['result'].get("id", None)
            GoogleName = response_data2['result'].get("name", None)
            for e in response_data2['result']['address_components']:
                for t in e['types']:
                    long_field[t] = e['long_name']
                    short_field[t] = e['short_name']

                    GoogleStreet_Number = long_field.get("street_number", None)
                    GoogleStreet = long_field.get("route", None)
                    GooglePostal_Code = long_field.get("postal_code", None)
                    GoogleCity = long_field.get("locality", None)
                    GoogleArea1 = long_field.get("administrative_area_level_1", None)
                    GoogleArea2 = long_field.get("administrative_area_level_2", None)
                    GoogleCountry = long_field.get("country", None)
                    GoogleCountryCode = short_field.get("country", None)
```